# How to get input value from ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a simple shopping cart in angular. Basically I have list of items and would like user to enter Quantity and then get the list of items that have Qty more than 0.

If the Qty is greater than 0 then I will add them into an array otherwise remove it.

I must be doing something wrong that is preventing me to get the Qty correct.

It works only first time but the second time it does not update.

**My controller:**

```
var extras1 = {Id:1,PackageName:"Balloons",Description:'Pack of 6',Cost:'$50.00',Qty:0}
var extras2 = {Id:2,PackageName:"Hot Chips",Description:'Fresh fried hot chips fully of yummy fat and cholesterol.',Cost:'$10.00',Qty:0}
var extras3 = {Id:3,PackageName:"Sausages",Description:'Hot sausages from premium offcuts',Cost:'$10.00',Qty:0}

$scope.extras =[extras1,extras2,extras3];

 $scope.extraSelected = function(){
    $scope.selectedExtra =[];
    angular.forEach($scope.extras, function(extra)
    {
       if(extra.Qty > 0 )
       {
           console.log('Extra added');
           $scope.selectedExtra.push(extra);
       }


    })
    console.log($scope.selectedExtra);
}
```

**Markup :**

```
 <div  ng-repeat="extra in extras"   class="text-left">
    <div  class="row-centered">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label class="col-md-1 col-sm-offset-1 step1-question" >{{$index + 1}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <span class="h4 step1-answer"> {{ extra.PackageName}} </span>
                <br/>
                <span class="h5"> {{ extra.Description}} </span>
                <br/>
                <span class="h5"> {{ extra.Cost}} </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type='text' class="form-control step1-answer text-center "
                   ng-model="extra.Qty"
                   placeholder="0" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding: 5px;height: 45px;"
                   ng-change="extraSelected(extra)"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the console log?

Comment: Very strange code, especially when calling slice. If you only want to get array of items, where Qty > 0, not need to remove items (because you are doing `$scope.selectedExtra = [];`)

Comment: And it will be more correct to use <input type='number'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something, like this?

```
<input type="number" ng-model="extra.Qty" ng-change="extraSelected()">

$scope.extraSelected = function () {
        $scope.selectedExtra = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.extras, function(extra) {
           if(extra.Qty > 0) {
               console.log('Extra added');
               $scope.selectedExtra.push(extra);
           }
        })
        console.log($scope.selectedExtra);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. that is exactly what I did after your comment but it only shows the Qty  for the first time. If I edit the Qty second time it does not update the Qty.

Comment: I try it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biggieman/hpo6L692/1/), and it works.  $scope.selectedExtra and $scope.extras with needed Qty

Comment: It does but only works 1 time, second time if the qty is updated to say 3 it will not show in console the updated value for Qty as 3.  Console still displays as Qty 1

Comment: In console.log all is fine, i can't understan whats wrong on your side. All changes are visible. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biggieman/hpo6L692/5/)

Comment: Thanks ..must be tired old eyes.It is showing correct Qty.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.extraSelected = function(extra){
    $scope.selectedExtra =[];
    angular.forEach($scope.extras, function(extra)
```

You have extra defined as the parameter being passed in and also as the parameter to the forEach function - the forEach is looping over the array with Qty is 0, so it will always be zero.

Change one of the function parameters so it doesnt clobber the other.

Lesson in functional scoping here...